# How can I recover my password for TrueCrypt Rescue Disk?

Tags: hard-drive, encryption, passwords, truecrypt, brute-force

I just found my 10year old HDD which has been fully encrypted with TrueCrypt 7.1 (Hidden Volume)

I inserted my TrueCrypt RescueDisk and had to put in my password, which I can't properly remember.
I do know which words could be possible and I think I typed in my password correctly once, because after typed in that password it asked me to modify diskpartition0.
Unfortunately I instantly forgot what I typed in, as it was a muscle memory attempt.

Is there a way to gain access to the HDD or Rescue Disk?
Should I use Hashcat to bruteforce my password or is there an easier way?

Comment: "Is there a way to gain access to the HDD or Rescue Disk?" - There is no way to access the data without the password.

Comment: Did I type in my password correctly though since it asked me to modify disk partition0 afterwards?

Comment: All I know is that TrueCrypt is cryptographically secure so the only way to access your data is with your password.  Only you can tell if you typed your password correctly. A brute force attack on your password likely is not feasible.

Comment: "it asked me to modify diskpartition0" This is a weak description. Who is "it"? What is the modification about? This sounds strange to me.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the best solution is indeed to use
[hashcat](https://hashcat.net/hashcat/).

A straight brute-force attack cannot succeed if the password was lengthy.
But since you know some words that were in the password, this could speed up
the cracking and make it feasible, but certainly not ensure success.

See for example the article
[Hashcat tutorial for beginners [updated 2021]](https://resources.infosecinstitute.com/topic/hashcat-tutorial-beginners/).